# Pandas: merge two rows within group by complex conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, group-by

I have a df as below;
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": ['company A', 'company A', 'company A', 'company B','company B', 'company B', 'company C', 'company C','company C','company C', 'company D', 'company D','company D'],
    'Sender': [28, 'delete', 'flag_source', 56, 28, 312, 'delete', 'flag_source', 78, 102, 26, 101, 96],
    'Receiver': [129, 28, 'delete', 172, 56, 28, 61, 'delete', 12, 78, 98, 26, 101],
    'Date': ['2020-04-12', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-20', '2019-02-11', '2019-01-31', '2018-04-02', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-29', '2019-11-29', '2019-10-01', '2020-04-03', '2020-01-30', '2019-10-18'],
    'Sender_type': ['house', 'temp', 'house', 'house', 'house', 'house', 'temp', 'house', 'house','house','house', 'temp', 'house'],
    'Receiver_type': ['house', 'house', 'temp', 'house','house','house','house', 'temp', 'house','house','house','house','temp'],
    'Price': [32, 50, 47, 21, 23, 19, 52, 39, 12, 22, 61, 53, 19]
})
```

And it is like this:

```
           ID       Sender Receiver        Date Sender_type Receiver_type  Price  
0   company A           28      129  2020-04-12       house         house  32 
1   company A       delete       28  2020-03-20        temp         house  50 # combine this row with below
2   company A  flag_source   delete  2020-03-20       house          temp  47 # combine this row with above
3   company B           56      172  2019-02-11       house         house  21 
4   company B           28       56  2019-01-31       house         house  23 
5   company B          312       28  2018-04-02       house         house  19 
6   company C       delete       61  2020-06-29        temp         house  52 # combine this row and below
7   company C  flag_source   delete  2020-06-29       house          temp  39 # combine this row with above
8   company C           78       12  2019-11-29       house         house  12 
9   company C          102       78  2019-10-01       house         house  22 
10  company D           26       98  2020-04-03       house         house  61 
11  company D          101       26  2020-01-30        temp         house  53 
12  company D           96      101  2019-10-18       house          temp  19
```

I wish to combine/merge two rows for each group 'ID' (company x) by the following rule: combine the row in 'Sender' that contains a'flag_source' and its above row into one new row. In this new row: the Sender is the flag_source, 'Revceiver' is its above value (remove the two 'delete' values), Date is the above date, Sender_type and Receiver_type are 'house', and 'Price' is the previous above value. Then remove the two rows. For example, for company A, it will combine line 1 and line 2 to generate the new row below:

```
ID        Sender        Receiver  Date        Sender_type  Receiver_type  Price
company A flag_source   28        2020-03-20  house        house          50
```

Then use this new row to replace the previous two lines. Same rules for the other groups(in this case only apply to company A and C). In the end, I wish to have a result like this:

```
           ID       Sender  Receiver        Date Sender_type Receiver_type  Price
0   company A           28       129  2020-04-12       house         house   32
1   company A  flag_source        28  2020-03-20       house         house   50 # new row
2   company B           56       172  2019-02-11       house         house   21
3   company B           28        56  2019-01-31       house         house   23
4   company B          312        28  2018-04-02       house         house   19
5   company C  flag_source        61  2020-06-29       house         house   52 # new row
6   company C           78        12  2019-11-29       house         house   12
7   company C          102        78  2019-10-01       house         house   22
8   company D           26        98  2020-04-03       house         house   61
9   company D          101        26  2020-01-30        temp         house   53
10  company D           96       101  2019-10-18       house          temp   19
```

Hopefully my explanation for the question is clear.

As this is a brief sample, the real case has many data like this, I wrote a loop but very slow and unproductive, so please help if you have any ideas and effective way. Many many thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": ['company A', 'company A', 'company A', 'company B','company B', 'company B', 'company C', 'company C','company C','company C', 'company D', 'company D','company D'],
    'Sender': [28, 'delete', 'flag_source', 56, 28, 312, 'delete', 'flag_source', 78, 102, 26, 101, 96],
    'Receiver': [129, 28, 'delete', 172, 56, 28, 61, 'delete', 12, 78, 98, 26, 101],
    'Date': ['2020-04-12', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-20', '2019-02-11', '2019-01-31', '2018-04-02', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-29', '2019-11-29', '2019-10-01', '2020-04-03', '2020-01-30', '2019-10-18'],
    'Sender_type': ['house', 'temp', 'house', 'house', 'house', 'house', 'temp', 'house', 'house','house','house', 'temp', 'house'],
    'Receiver_type': ['house', 'house', 'temp', 'house','house','house','house', 'temp', 'house','house','house','house','temp'],
    'Price': [32, 50, 47, 21, 23, 19, 52, 39, 12, 22, 61, 53, 19]
})

flaggedData = (df[df["Sender"] == "flag_source"])

for i,row in flaggedData.iterrows():  # Row variable contains row having sender as flag_source

    deleteRow = df[df.index == i-1].values[0]   # delete variable contains row having sender as delete

    combined = [row[0],  # ID
                row[1],  # Sender
                deleteRow[2],  # Receiver
                deleteRow[3],  # Date
                row[4],  # Sender_type
                deleteRow[5],  # Receiver_type
                deleteRow[6]]  # Price

    df.loc[i-1] = combined  # replace with new values
    df = df.drop(index=i)  # drop old values

df = df.reset_index()  # resent index for better access on future.
print(df.loc[1])
```

**I am assuming that every "delete" row is above on "flag_source" row. Read the comments if you still don't understand, comment your doubt.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only need to delete the second row of each pair and replace some values in the remaining rows.

```
df = df[dd.Receiver == 'delete']
df.Sender = df.Sender.str.replace('delete', 'flag_source')
df.Sender_type = df.Sender_type.str.replace('temp', 'house')
```

Comment: Unless `flag_source` and `temp` are just examples and the real data can have any values... in which case looping from bottom to top is your only option, but perhaps it is faster to just create a mask while looping and drop all intended rows at once

Answer (score 0):

If the delete/flag_source are always on the same Date, and if there's no other rows on that Date + ID, you can use an groupby aggregate function on the ID and Date to avoid using a long loop. If your data isn't in the correct order you can always `sort_values` it beforehand.

```
cols = df.columns

new_df = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date']).aggregate({
    'Sender': 'last', 
    'Receiver': 'first', 
    'Sender_type': 'last', 
    'Receiver_type': 'first', 
    'Price': 'first'
    }).reset_index()

# Reorder as per original data
new_df[cols].sort_values(['ID', 'Date'], ascending=[1, 0])
```